# How to pass (;) semicolons symbol one page to other in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater on `question.aspx` page that is show list of the article title. When i click on the title the title value pass to the `article.aspx` page.

But **problem** in that if in the title content (;) semicolons symbol on the second page do not show text after this symbol.

Example

If title is---- on this first page

"this is title ; this text will hide "

on the second page its show only

"this is title"

**first page**

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton" CssClass="article" runat="server" OnClick="gotoarticle"
    Text='<%#Eval("title") %>' Font-Bold="true" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("title")  %> ' >
```

---

```
protected void gotoarticle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)sender;
    string[] argument = link.CommandArgument.Split(';');
    string title = argument[0];

    Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/article/article.aspx?title={0}",Server.UrlEncode(title)), false);  
}
```

**second page**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    title.Text = Request.QueryString["title"];
}
```

Comment: unless I am misunderstanding the Q, `gototanswerpage1` is removing the text after the semicolon

Comment: When you look at the rendered **question.aspx** page (right-click and select View Source or Page Source), do you see the semi-colon ';' in the rendered links?

Answer (score 3):

If you need the entire Title text from your `LinkButton`'s CommandArgument, change your `gototanswerpage1` method to:

```
protected void gotoanswerpage1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton)sender;
    string title = link.CommandArgument;

    Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/article/article.aspx?title={0}",Server.UrlEncode(title)), false);  
}
```

And then decode your title in your second page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    title.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["title"]);
}
```